# Using variables in case statement, VHDL

Tags: vhdl

In VHDL, can I update a variable inside a case statement that uses that same variable?
The case statement is inside a rising_edge(clk) block. Thank you.

```
                    case State_var is
                    when "00" => 
                        if (Valid= '1') then
                            State_var := "00";
                        else
                            State_var := "01";
                        end if;
                    when "01" => 
                        if (Valid = '1') then
                            State_var := "00";
                        else
                            State_var := "10";
                        end if;
                    when "10" => 
                        if (Valid = '1') then
                            State_var := "11";
                        else
                            State_var := "01";
                        end if;
                    when "11" => 
                        if (Valid = '1') then
                            State_var := "11";
                        else
                            State_var := "10";
                        end if;
                    when others => null;
                end case;
```

Comment: Yes. (extra chars...)

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem doing this - I do it all the time.

The `case` selection is evaluated once based on the value of your state variable at that instant, and updates that you make to the state variable will not cause the `case` statement to immediately transition to new states.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. Also you can use only `case` statement:

```
process(...)
...
variable state: std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
...
begin
...
state := Valid & State_var;
...
    case state is
            when "000"  => State_var := "01";
            when "001"  => State_var := "10";
            when "010"  => State_var := "01";
            when "011"  => State_var := "10";
            when "100"  => State_var := "00";
            when "101"  => State_var := "00";
            when others => State_var := "11";
    end case;
...
end process;
```

Answer (score -2):

Why are you using a variable for your state machine?  A state machine should be a registered signal, that's the point of a state machine.  I would not recommend using a variable here.  It will generate a lot of extra combinatorial decode logic and might have some race conditions.

Comment: Variables for State work perfectly well provided you take the different assignment semantics into account! Especially here - where there is ONE test of the variable - where would that decode logic come from? After all, you can create registers - thus state - using variables. The biggest advantage of a signal over a variable (for this role) is that some simulators won't display variables

Comment: @BrianDrummond With signals for state, we can divide a state machine into two parts(combinational logic and sequential logic), which sometimes makes the structure of a state machine more clear and maintainable.

Comment: @Wisatbff - the claim that it is clearer "your" way is contentious... :)

Comment: Variable vs. signal and registered vs. combinatorial are completely orthogonal.